# webpack build all the packages in dependencies block of package.json even I didn't imported the package in my code

Tags: webpack, package.json

It seems like webpack will build all the dependencies in package.json, even the package is not imported in my code.

I found when I put some packages in dependencies block in package.json, after build with webpack, the dist files will include it. While if it's put in devDependencies block, it will not.

Feel confused with it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post you webpack config file? That would greatly help in detecting your problem.

To give you some pointers:

- webpack itself does not care about package.json.
- webpack only performs static analysis which means it will only build modules that are imported/required somewhere in your code

Please post your webpack config. It will help us tell if your problem is with webpack at all.